# Image doesn't appear when mailing python 3

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, smtplib, mime-mail

I am creating a program where I send an image to someone by mail with Tkinter and smtplib in python 3. Everything works fine but when someone receives the email it looks like this:

[image]

but I want it to look like this:

[image]

does anyone know why the { ? } shows up?

the code I use to send the photo is this:

```py
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage

msg = MIMEMultipart()

fp = open(image, 'rb')
photo = MIMEImage(fp.read(), _subtype="jpg")
fp.close()
msg.attach(photo)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Without any code, it will be hard to help you solve your problem.

Comment: okay, I added the code I use @j_4321, can you help me with that? thanks

Comment: Please make it a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), for instance I don't know what `msg` is exactly in your code.